# Dojo dGrid with Observable Store Not updating with Single Record

Tags: dojo, observable, dgrid

When using an Observable store for a dGrid a call to the `notify()` method will update a record. See this example: [Git Hub Drgid Example](https://github.com/kriszyp/dgrid/blob/real-time-example/test/real-time.html)

However, when there is only one record, notify does not appear to notify the record. This can be seen in the above example by removing all but one stock in `stocks.json`.

Is this a known issue or is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

There is a work around for this. Set the `cleanEmptyObservers: false` on your dGrids. Thanks to https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/925